# MySQL query to find all child elements

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query, mysql-8.0

I have two tables :

**elements** :

| id_element | name |
| --- | --- |
| elem1 | CPV |
| elem2 | CBO |
| elem3 | CPV |

**parenting** (Which is referencing **elements**)

| id_element | id_element_elements |
| --- | --- |
| elem1 | null |
| elem2 | elem1 |
| elem3 | elem1 |
| elem4 | elem2 |

Is there a query to find all the child elements from a single element in this case ?

Looking for something like :

| id_element | id_child |
| --- | --- |
| elem1 | elem2 |
| elem1 | elem3 |
| elem2 | elem4 |

Comment: MySQL - Ver 8.0.17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT *
         FROM parenting 
         WHERE id_element_elements = 'elem1'
       UNION ALL
         SELECT parenting.*
         FROM cte
         JOIN parenting ON cte.id_element = parenting.id_element_elements )
SELECT id_element_elements id_element, id_element id_child
FROM cte
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aa37cdc4aeabc2e41c35d2549cac37be)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
p.id_element_elements,p.id_element
FROM elements e 
right join parenting p 
On e.id_element =p.id_element_elements
Where p.id_element_elements is not null
```